# how to hard orientation lock my app in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

so I'm making an app that is all about device orientation - so I *don't* want the app to react in any way when I rotate it - ie if I put an arrow at the top of the screen, and they turn the phone (or iPad) to the left, I want the arrow to now be pointing to the left - if they turn the phone upside down, I want it pointing down.  Also if they turn the phone to the left - I want geometry reader to still tell me that the phone is much higher than it is wide.

I have no idea how to do this.  All the reading I've done has stuff about appdelegates and view controllers - and I just have an App with views.

I've tried adding this to the .plist file:

```xml
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
```

and it had no effect whatsoever that I could tell.

How can I just completely disable *any* rotation functionality as far as my app is concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 50) {
            Text("testing orientation portrait only")
            Text("testing orientation portrait only")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - I was not sure how to connect the "app" world to the app delegate world